# Create a desktop shortcut to a specific Remote Desktop session in the new Microsoft Store Remote Desktop app

Tags: shortcuts, windows-11

I use Windows 11 as my daily driver and I manage quite a few VMs that I access through the new Remote Desktop app that can  be found on the MS store (the one with the red icon, not the old one that is bundled to Windows).

I would like to create desktop shortcuts to each of these VMs, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

There is a way to do that in the old desktop app, which involves creating a desktop shortcut with the following target:

```
mstsc.exe /v:IPADDRESSOFTHEREMOTEDESKTOPCONNECTION
```

I wasn't able to find anything similar with regard to the new app, however.

Any feedback would be more than welcome, thanks in advance!